# Add site collection administrator error in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

My SharePoint server is SharePoint 2013 and windows Server is 2012 and SQL Server 2012

I changed users password now I want to add site collection administrator in a site collection

I go to settings than site collection administrator than add user after I click the ok button it gives error and does not add another site collection administrator

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: It gives just correlation id: something like guide, I searched that Id but found no result

Comment: did you check the ULS logs for that correlation id? use merge-splog command to check the error details? which users password you change? did you change the brower(sometime it is browsers issue) or try from different PC.

Comment: How to check ULS log that id I have downloaded the ULS log viewer but don't know how to find this error can you help me

Comment: if you permission to run the powershell script then do via powershell. Merge-SPLogFile -correlation "GUID " -Path "C:\FarmMergedLog.log" ....recreate the error and get the fresh Correltion ID and put in above command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stsadm command to add site collection administrator.

```
stsadm.exe -o siteowner -url <url> [-ownerlogin <DOMAIN\name>] [-secondarylogin <DOMAIN\name>]
```